# Existence of a unique topology on $X$ given closure operator

Tags: general-topology

> Suppose $f: \mathcal{P}(X) \to \mathcal{P}(X)$ is a function that
>
> satisfies, for every set $A,B \subseteq X$
>
> $(C_1): f(\emptyset) = \emptyset$
>
> $(C_2): A \subseteq f(A)$
>
> $(C_3): f(A \cup B) =f(A) \cup f(B)$
>
> $(C_4): f(f(A)) = f(A)$
>
> Prove that there exists a unique topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $X$ such
>   that for all $A \subseteq X$, $\text{Cl}(A) = f(A)$, where $\text{Cl}(A)$ denotes the
>   closure of the set $A$, with respect to the topology $\mathcal{T}$

**My attempt**:

I defined $\mathcal{T}:= \{A \subseteq X \mid f(X \setminus A) = X \setminus A\}$

and I managed to prove with $C_1, C_2, C_3$ that this set is a topology, and that it is unique, if it exists. So I only need to show that it exists, for which I have to prove that $\text{Cl}(A) = f(A)$ whenever $A \subseteq X$

I can show that $f(A) \supseteq \text{Cl}(A)$. I just need the other inclusion and I'm done!

Any hints?

Comment: The closure $\mathrm{cl}(A)$ is the intersection of all closed sets that contain $A$. So it would be enough to show that $f(A)$ is closed.

Comment: "and that it is unique, if it exists" $-$  $\mathcal{T}$ definitely exists, you just defined it.

Comment: This is "Kuratowski closure axiom"

Comment: I made a mistake. I actually had trouble proving the other inclusion (I edited the post accordingly)

Comment: What do you mean by "I only need to show it exists." when clearly it is defined, is nof empty and exists.

Comment: It may help to show f is increasing.

Comment: Showing that a topology exists WITH the condition I want

Comment: No, we must prove that $f(A) = Cl_{\mathcal{T}}(A) := \{x \in X \mid \forall V \in \mathcal{V}_{\mathcal{T}}(x): V \cap A \neq \emptyset\}$. I don't see at all how this is obvious?

Comment: If you can show that $f(A)⊇\operatorname{Cl}(A)$ for all $A\in\mathcal{P}(X)$ then in particular substituting $f(A)$ in place of $A$, you have, $$\operatorname{Cl}(f(A))\subseteq f(f(A))=f(A)$$From this you can conclude that $f(A)$ is closed. Now follow @jabo's hint.

Comment: One thing that may be useful is to show that, if $A\subseteq B$, then $f(A)\subseteq f(B)$. (Hint: since $A\subseteq B$, we have $B=A\cup(B\setminus A)$. Apply $f$ to both sides.)

Comment: Also, (a) $A\subseteq{\rm Cl}(A)$. (b) Due to the way you've defined $\cal T$, we have that $f$ of a closed set is itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you define the closure of $A$ as $\operatorname{Cl}_{\mathcal{T}}(A) = \{x \in X: \forall O \in \mathcal{T}: x \in O \to O \cap A \neq \emptyset \}$, i.e. the set of adherent points of $A$.

For closure operators it's more convenient (and dual to the way we can define interiors) to use

$$\operatorname{Cl}_{\mathcal{T}}(A) = \bigcap \{F \subseteq X: A \subseteq F, F \text{ closed }\} (\ast)$$

which says that the closure of $A$ is the smallest closed set that contains $A$ as a subset.

It's a classic excercise in introductory topology to show that these definitions are equivalent.

Also the closure axioms (as in the case of interior operators) imply that $f$ is monotonic: $A \subseteq B$ implies $f(A) \subseteq f(B)$:

Proof: $A \subseteq B$ implies $A \cup B = B$ so $(C_3)$ tells us that $f(B) = f(A \cup B) = f(A) \cup f(B)$ so that $f(A) \subseteq f(B)$ follows.

Also note that in your definition we could just as easily have defined $A$ is closed iff $f(A) = A$.

Now if $A$ is a subset of $X$ we have that $A \subseteq f(A)$ by $(C_2)$ and $f(A)$ is closed by $(C_4)$, as $f(f(A)) = f(A)$. So $f(A)$ is one of the closed sets we take the intersection of in $(\ast)$ so that $\operatorname{Cl}_{\mathcal{T}}(A) \subseteq f(A)$.

On the other hand, if $F$ is one of the closed sets in the right hand side of $(\ast)$, we know that $A \subseteq F$ and $F$ is closed so that by monotonicity 
we know that $f(A) \subseteq f(F) = F$, and as this holds for all $F$, $f(A) \subseteq \operatorname{Cl}_{\mathcal{T}}(A)$ and we have equality of $f$ and the closure operator of $\mathcal{T}$ for any $A \subseteq X$.

Note the duality with your earlier interior operator [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2664654/4280). Given an interior operator $i$ we can define a closure operator $c(A) = X\setminus i(X\setminus A)$. Standard set theory gives that axioms $(I_1)-(I_4)$ there then are equivalent to $(C_1)-(C_4)$ above. We can reduce one excercise to the other, essentially. $i(A) = X\setminus c(X\setminus A)$ allows us to go from a closure operator to an interior operator in the same way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I just solved the problem using the hints in the comments, by showing that $f(B)$ is the smallest closed set that contains $B$, hence $f(B) = cl(B)$. Your answer shows that my attempt is correct!

Comment: @Math_QED Glad I could help. I've always loved these "basic" exercises to show the equivalence of different ways to define a topology (e.g. also by neighbourhood systems or filter convergence systems  or rather obscurely by the boundary operator etc.)

Comment: Is the converse of the claim statement true? That is, is it true that if $X$ be a non-empty set and $\tau$ be a topology on $X$ then there exists a unique closure operator on $X$ such that the topology induced by it is unique?

Comment: @user170039  yes, the standard closure induced by $\tau$ is such.

Comment: Where can I find a proof of this fact?

Comment: I mean the proof of uniqueness of the closure operator of which you talked earlier.

Comment: @user170039 it's obvious. It follows from the above fact.

Comment: If you don't mind then can you come to [this room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72901/general-chat-with-user-170039). I am having trouble to understand it and don't want to lengthen the comment chain here.

Comment: The part that I am having trouble is the following. Let $(X,τ)$ be a topological space and $\text{Cl}_τ$ be the closure operator induced by $τ$ and $\text{Cl}$ be any other closure operator which induces the same topology $τ$. Then how can I show that **for all** $A$ we have $\text{Cl}_τ(A)=\text{Cl}(A)$?

Comment: @user170039 both closures must equal the intersection of all $\tau$-closed sets that contain $A$. As $\tau$ is given, these are the same closures.

Comment: Thanks. I think I [figured it out](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46203283#46203283).